# Change column values on specific rows only R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R, and I need to clean a specific column but not on all rows. For example, for rows with

```
df$score > 100
```

I want to divide it by 10 and replace the original value.

How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using mtcars as example, you can do it like this:

```
mtcars$mpg <- ifelse(mtcars$mpg > 100, mtcars$mpg/10, mtcars$mpg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, we can assign in place for those rows that match the condition set in 'i'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[score>100, score := score/10]
```