# How to replace only selected values while retaining original column values in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a column in a dataframe (df) as say set. I want to specifically replace only values 5 and 6, and retain the original values from set. I used the following code

```
set <- c(3,4,5,5,6,6,10,11)
df$set <- as.factor(df$set)
df$set <- ifelse(df$set == 5 | df$set =="6", 5.5, df$set)
```

The output I get for df$set is `1.0 2.0 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.0 6.0` instead of my expected output `3,4,5.5,5.5,5.5,5.5,10,11`

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197578/change-column-values-on-specific-rows-only-r) example, but it does not seem to work.

Why is this so? How can  correct it

Comment: Because you getting confused between the levels and values of the factor you've created. Try as numeric or as character to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks. I retained it to as.numeric, replaces it, and then converted it back into as.factor. That solved it!

Comment: Why are you bothering with factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand the `levels` created by `as.factor`

```
df <- data.frame(
  set = c(3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 10, 11)
)

# numeric
ifelse(df$set == 5 | df$set == 6, 5.5, df$set)
# [1]  3.0  4.0  5.5  5.5  5.5  5.5 10.0 11.0

# character
ifelse(df$set == "5" | df$set == "6", "5.5", as.character(df$set))
# [1] "3"   "4"   "5.5" "5.5" "5.5" "5.5" "10"  "11"

# factor
ifelse(df$set == "5" | df$set == "6", "5.5", as.factor(df$set))
# [1] "1"   "2"   "5.5" "5.5" "5.5" "5.5" "5"   "6"

levels(as.factor(df$set))
# [1] "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "10" "11"
#
# 1 = "3"
# 2 = "4"
# 3 = "5"
# 4 = "6"
# 5 = "10"
# 6 = "11"
```